# How was the expression relating two general solutions to $x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+2\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}- 2u = 0$ obtained?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

`This was the question:`

> Find the general solution of $$x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+2\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}- 2u = 0$$

---

`At the end of the solution it says:`

> One general solution $u(x,y)$ is $$u(x,y)=\exp(y)\color{red}{\overbrace{f\left(x\exp\left(-\frac12 y\right) \right)}^{\color{blue}{\large{=f(p)}}}}$$ where $\color{blue}{p=x\exp\left(-\frac12 y\right)}$
>
> Another general solution $u(x,y)$ is $$u(x,y)=x^2\color{#180}{g}\color{red}{\overbrace{\left(x\exp\left(-\frac12 y\right) \right)}^{\color{blue}{\large{=p}}}}$$ where $\color{#180}{g}$ is an arbitrary function of $\color{blue}{p}$; clearly $$\color{purple}{\fbox{$g(p)=\frac{f(p)}{p^2}$}}$$

---

My question regarding this solution is the box marked $\color{purple}{\mathrm{purple}}$. Since $p^2=x^2\exp(-y)$ and $f(p)=f\left(x\exp\left(-\frac12 y\right) \right)$. So $$g(p)=\frac{f\left(x\exp\left(-\frac12 y\right) \right)}{x^2\exp(-y)}$$

How does it follow that $\color{purple}{\fbox{$g(p)=\frac{f(p)}{p^2}$}}$?

Comment: Equate the two solutions.

Comment: @deinst Thanks, I understand completely now. I should have known better, can't believe I didn't spot equating them to get that expression in purple. Since this question is now answered, would you like to make an answer; I feel you deserve some rep for this. Thanks again.

Comment: Since I have received a downvote; as ever, I would like to know what could be improved on this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just equating the two solutions, showing that they are not really different.

The two solutions are
$$u(x,y)=\exp(y)f(p)=x^2 g(p)$$
so, solving for $g(p)$ we get
$$g(p)=\frac{f(p)}{x^2 \exp(-y)}$$
and since 
$$p=x\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}y\right)$$
we have
$$g(p)=\frac{f(p)}{p^2}$$

Comment: Future Readers would benefit from a more detailed explanation, as here you have merely repeated a Comment that you made on the Question, so the OP will know the context but others will likely find your Answer overly terse.